# find() and with() return all models, instead of model with children

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading

I have a model `Survey` that has related child records defined in the model `ScaleQuestions`.

I want to create a route where I can look at a single survey and see along with that all of its child scale questions. I've created this route, trying to eager load one survey and all of its children: but it returns all of the survey models:

```
    public function survey($id) {
        $survey = \App\Gt\Lib\Survey::find($id)
            ->with('scale_questions')
            ->get();
        ;
       \dump($id);
        \dump($survey);
        return view('gt/admin/survey')->with('survey',$survey);
```

There are (currently) 43 surveys, and only 10 child scale questions, but the dump clearly shows me it loaded the 43 surveys.

```
Collection {#684 ▼
  #items: array:43 [▼
    0 => Survey {#208 ▶}
    1 => Survey {#209 ▶}
    2 => Survey {#210 ▶}
    3 => Survey {#211 ▶}
```

When I take out `get()`, I get a builder object, which I don't know what to do with:

```
Builder {#161 ▼
  #query: Builder {#154 ▶}
  #model: Survey {#165 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: array:1 [▶]
  #macros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:10 [▶]
}
```

It seems that it's an unprocessed query, since I can't get any properties off of it:

```
public function survey($id) {
    $survey = \App\Gt\Lib\Survey::find($id)
        ->with('scale_questions');
        \dump($survey->id);
```

Gives me this:

```
ErrorException in AdminSurveysController.php line 31: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id
```

How do I eager-load the single survey and only its child questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do the `find()` last:

```
$survey = \App\Gt\Lib\Survey::with('scale_questions')->find($id);
```